# Entity manager factory name is already registered

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cxf

I have a server setup that functions properly when it is running, but during startup I get all messages 2 times and a warning from Hibernate saying `Entity manager factory name is already registered` . I am using Spring, Hibernate and CXF. I feel my setup should be in line with the documentation, but it must be something I am missing. I have found a lot of similar cases where people point to Spring MVC, but I don't think that is the problem for me.

in my web.xml I have:

```
<listener>
    <description>desc</description>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I have the following in WEB-INF:

- **applicationContext.xml** with component scan to `@Configuration`
  classes for java-config and component scans for `@Component`.
- **cxf-servlet.xml** also with component scan.

Is it something I have missed?

---

*update 1:* 
Looks like the problem goes away if I remove component-scan from cxf-servlet.xml, but then it is not able to process my `@Configurable` classes with `@Inject`. Now I am more confused as to how CXF and Spring fires up the Spring context.

*update 2:* 
It is something related to having component scan in both cxf-servlet and applicationContext. Everything works, but it is loading stuff 2 times at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to filter out Hibernate pojo classes/packages that are annotated with @Component, and try to make sure one that creates the entity manager bean is also filtered out.

Classes annotated with @Component are scanned by default,in case of below declaration.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xyz" />
```

Comment: where do you mean I should be filtering? I have a class (`@Configuration`) creating the entity manager (`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`). Should this be filtered out somehow?

Comment: while not spot on, this response put me on the right track